# how do I deploy to a custom service with the appengine gradle plugin?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle

I have seen all the parameters from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle-reference). But none of them allow to override the `service` parameter from the generated yaml.

I tried using `deployables = app.yaml` with the app.yaml below but it gives me a 500 error:

```
runtime: java7
threadsafe: True
api_version: '1.0'
service: backend
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
skip_files: app.yaml
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `services` parameter is what determines the service's name, meaning the service the deployment is directed to.

So there is no way to overwrite the `services` parameter because as soon as you change it you're simply deploying to a different service.

So if you want to just change a service's name you should:

- simply deploy with the new name, creating a new service
- delete the old service using [`gcloud app services delete`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/services/delete):

  ```
  $ gcloud app services delete old_service_name
  ```

The order of the steps may matter for your case, you may want to reverse them.

Comment: And the deployment error is caused by the content of your yaml file - that's a standard env one, scripts are not optional and `app.yaml` itself can't be skipped.

Comment: `simply deploy with the new name, creating a new service` => where do I put the name ? in `web.xml`, `build.gradle`, `gcloud command line` ? To deploy, I just do `./gradlew appengineDeploy` at the moment

Comment: In `appengine-web.xml`, see `service` row in [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#syntax) table (or `module`)