# Google Cloud Routes HTTP and HTTPS differently

Tags: django, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

## TL;DR

Google Cloud Platform routing dispatch behaves differently for HTTP and HTTPS, and I can't figure out (or find a reference as to) why.

## The Setup

1. I have a `default` service with this (absolutely standard) `app.yaml`:

   ```
   runtime: python
   env: flex
   entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT <project>.wsgi

   beta_settings:
     cloud_sql_instances: <instance-connection-string>

   runtime_config:
     python_version: 3
   ```

   It's a Django app serving the API and the Admin Interface.
2. I have a `frontend` service with this (again, absolutely standard) `app.yaml`:

   ```
   service: frontend
   runtime: python27
   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: true

   handlers:
   - url: /static/(.*)
     static_files: build/static/\1
     upload: build/static/(.*)
   - url: /.*
     static_files: build/index.html
     upload: build/index.html
   ```

   It's a ReactJS application that consumes the API and acts as a frontend.
3. Then, I have this `dispatch.yaml`:

   ```
   dispatch:

   - url: "*/api/*"
     service: default

   - url: "*/admin/*"
     service: default

   - url: "*/*"
     service: frontend
   ```

   Meaning "serve `/api/...` and `/admin/...` from the `default` service, and the rest from the `frontend` service". Alright.

## The Problem

When I go to `http://<project-id>.appspot.com` (note the HTTP), everything works as expected. To wit:

- http://aksinin-191616.appspot.com/api/content/ is the API,
- http://aksinin-191616.appspot.com/admin/en/ is the Admin Interface,
- http://aksinin-191616.appspot.com/ is the frontend.

But when I do the same with `https://<project-id>.appspot.com` (note the HTTP**S**), *everything* is *always* redirected to the frontend. To wit:

- https://aksinin-191616.appspot.com/api/content/ is the frontend,
- https://aksinin-191616.appspot.com/admin/en/ is the frontend,
- https://aksinin-191616.appspot.com/ is the frontend.

What's even more absurd is that *the frontend's subdomain*, i.e. `https://frontend-dot-<project-id>.appspot.com`, returns everything as expected, including the API and the Admin Interface, both in HTTP and in HTTPS.

- https://frontend-dot-aksinin-191616.appspot.com/api/content/ is the API,
- https://frontend-dot-aksinin-191616.appspot.com/admin/en/ is the Admin Interface,
- https://frontend-dot-aksinin-191616.appspot.com/ is the frontend.

## The Question

What incantation am I missing to make it work as expected with HTTPS? I really don't want to serve the admin interface over HTTP...

Comment: Why don't you simply revert the roles of your services, keeping in mind that the default service is the one getting all unexpected crap that is not matched by any rules... i.e.exactly what your're apparently expecting from your currently named `frontend` service. Call the other one `backend` or whatever _specific_ function it performs and leave the default service do the default/kitchen sink job it already performs ;) It can be a bit tricky to rename services, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575114/how-do-i-deploy-to-a-custom-service-with-the-appengine-gradle-plugin/47577207#47577207

Comment: Thanks. It's mainly for historical reasons, and if I end up unable to actually solve the problem I may do just that. But I'd like to try and figure it out if I can.

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured it out (turns out it's not a problem in GCP).

In case somebody else runs into a similar issue in the future, here's what happened to me:

- I had some HTTPS-only security cookie that went stale, probably between service updates.
- Trying to use the Django backend raised an error, which caused GCP to pass the request to the next matching handler (which was the frontend catch-all URL). So, instead of getting the Admin Interface or an error, I was silently redirected to the frontend.
- Trying to use the same backend via HTTP didn't pass that cookie, so it worked,
- Trying to use the same backend via the `frontend-dot-<project-id>.appspot.com` subdomain didn't pass the cookie, because its domain was `<project-id>.appspot.com`.

So, after all, it was as simple as clearing my browsing data. Huh.